# onSubmit in link duplicate

Tags: html, hyperlink

i recently found this:

```
<a href="https://validator.w3.org/" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://validator.w3.org/'); return false;">https://validator.w3.org/</a>
```

Is there a reason why there is the onclick in this link that does the same as the normal target attribute, instead of just put a

```
target="_blank"
```

in there
? Are there any valid reasons to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It opens the link into new window.
If you get rid onclick function the link will open in the same window.

Another way to do that is

```
<a href="https://validator.w3.org/" target="_blank">https://validator.w3.org/</a>
```

Comment: Sry, I updated my question. I meant why not just use the target="_blank" option.

Comment: I don't find any good reason. If browser has no javascript enabled the link never works. I suggest use target blank